# pd.to_numeric(downcast="integer") and astype(int) don't work

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe and a column that is interpreted as `float` when read.
I just tried these two approaches:

```
data["column"] = data["column"].astype(int, errors="ignore")
```

And

```
data["column"] = pd.to_numeric(data["column"], downcast="integer", errors="coerce")
```

But when doing

```
print(data.dtypes)
```

I still get that the data type of this columns is float. What should I do?

Comment: Cause np.nan is type of float by default. mixed type will downcast from int to float

Comment: @YOBEN_S so there is no way to make this column as type int just because of the NaNs?

Comment: data["column"] = data["column"].fillna(0).astype(int, errors="ignore")

Comment: An experimental feature in `pandas 1.0.0` introduces a scalar `NA` that lets you change to type `int`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values